# web scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup errror TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
anchors = soup.find_all('a')`all_links = set()`for link in anchors:
if (link.get('href') != '#'):`linkText = "https://www.newegg.com/" + `link.get('href')``all_links.add(link)`print(linkText)
```

`#How should my last three lines of code be corrected?`````

Answer (score 0):

Provide default value to `link.get('href')` function: `link.get('href', '')`. The default is `None` so you get error if link doesn't have 'href' attribute.

```
anchors = soup.find_all('a')
all_links = set()

for link in anchors:
    if link.get('href', '') != '#':
        linkText = "https://www.newegg.com/" + link.get('href', '')
        all_links.add(link)
        print(linkText)
```

Comment: Thank you very much